# React Native Webview shows white blank screen

Tags: react-native, webview

I'm trying to use react-native-webview (Android app) and I'm getting a white screen when I try to load my website:
https://lostlaowai.app:4432/?ID=1105T140W4iUserAgentAllow3

I've also noticed that the WebView loads https://www.google.com/ but not google.com without the https:// and ending /
Could this be related?

When you run it in your browser is works fine. But I can't get it to load in the WebView. I've spent the past few days reading all sorts of posts describing similar issues of WebView white screens but none of the potential solutions work... here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
    Dimensions,
    Alert
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
    const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
    const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <WebView
                source={{ uri: 'https://lostlaowai.app:4432/?ID=1105T140W4iUserAgentAllow3' }}
                onError={syntheticEvent => {
                    const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;
                    Alert.alert('WebView error: ', "" + nativeEvent);
                }}
                onHttpError={syntheticEvent => {
                    const { nativeEvent } = syntheticEvent;
                    console.warn(
                        'WebView received error status code: ',
                        nativeEvent.statusCode,
                    );
                }}
                mixedContentMode={'always'}
                geolocationEnabled={true}
                ignoreSslError={true}
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                scalesPageToFit={true}
                startInLoadingState={false}
                style={{flex: 1, width: deviceWidth, height: deviceHeight}}
            />
        </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

My specs:

react-native-cli: 2.0.1

react-native: 0.61.2

node: v10.16.3

Device: Xiaomi Note

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Works on my phone, using this snack: https://snack.expo.io/SJKKceZYB https://i.imgur.com/hmCUH1T.png Have you tried using a real device?

Comment: @iuliu.net Thanks for your comment! But this does not solve my problem. Notice that I mention at the end of my question that my device is a Xiaomi Note. A lot of my Chinese users with Chinese phones seem to be having trouble. Does the WebView rely on Google Play Services, which Chinese phones don't have (as Google is banned in China)?

Comment: I'm currently in Hong Kong and as mentioned in my question, I am able to get 'https://www.google.com/' to load but not 'google.com'. I'm wondering if the reason why 'google.com' is not working is the same reason that my own website won't load?